# Excel 2016 Bar chart with Total and Count

Tags: excel, charts, bar-chart

I have excel sheet with category and Price. Category are repeating

[image]

As category was repeating. I could not make proper chart. So make temporary table with removing duplicate data from category and another column with **sumif** formula and output as below
[image]

and created chart from as below
[image]

Now My question is can we add count of category as well with Total on chart but not separate bars. Please show me the path

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether something like this would serve:

[image: SO39318891 example]

It is a stacked bar chart with the upper series not filled. The values for the second series are derived with:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,F2)
```

where `Category` for your raw data is in ColumnA and in ColumnF Row 1 for your summary table.

May not suit as (a) was created in Excel 2013 and (b) the red numbers might stray up and down too much if their range is great.

Comment: I know we can use countif and I already did that but I wanted to show it as label on the same bar chart